# Galaxy Mini bricked: black screen

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have a Galaxy Mini GT-5570 phone.

Last night I installed "ROM Manager" and tried to partition my SD card. It requires to reboot my phone and I confirmed that, so it shut down my phone. Then it can't boot anymore -- all I get is just a black screen!

Unfortunately, I read that ROM Manager can cause hard brick for Galaxy Mini lately...

I tried all possible solutions found in the Internet but nothing works. So I decided to try the USB JIG method as it can force my phone to boot to download mode. The point is that I can't find 300k resistor then can I try 330k or it's dengerous?

Is there another method to revive my phone back ??

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to rig your usb to enter download mode.

You  just need to hold **Vol UP + Home** then **plug your USB cable** to your PC.

If you haven't started ODIN in flash mode or did not install bootloader drivers for the Mini, download mode will not show up, and you'll see only a black screen.

Comment: I've tried that way...Odin can detect my phone but while flashing it stops at "Setup Connection",I've read that maybe problem with Samsung driver but it isn't !

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable? It might be loose. I had a similar experience with an HTC Legend, the flashing constantly interrupted because of the old cable.

Comment: @Wisdom have you tried it on different computers?